# Can I create a stateless static class in MVC back-end

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, state

I have an MVC application that contains a static class providing a boolean value to the rest of the program. My issue is that I want the boolean to reset with each call to the back-end. I want it to be "stateless", getting initialized to false for each and every back-end call. I'll then set it to true as needed. For instance, consider the following where from the `Index` view we load the `About` view and then afterwards load the `Contact` view ...

```
public static class BooleanProvider
{
    public static bool theBool = false;
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
        BooleanProvider.theBool = true;

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        //I want BooleanProvider.theBool to be false here, since it's a different call, even though we set it to true in the About() method

        return View();
    }
}
```

When I check `BooleanProvider.theBool` at the commented line, it's set to true. Is there a way to "re-initialize" the boolean with every call? I'd rather not make the class instantiable and have to new it up with each controller call, but maybe there is no other way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The other choice is not make it static and then in the constructor set it to false.

Comment: Why use a single boolean for this purpose? Seems confusing.  Why not something like a static Dictionary, where the keys are something related to each back-end method call you wanted to "reinitialize" the boolean with, and the dictionary values are booleans?  Plus, if this is asynchronous at all, trying to link one boolean to a bunch of asynchronous calls will be a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Dependency injection for that.

**dotnetcore solution**

Scoped Lifetime is exactly what you needed.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#scoped

At your Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddScoped<BooleanProvider>();
    // ...
}
```

and at your HomeController

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly BooleanProvider _booleanProvider;
    public HomeController (BooleanProvider booleanProvider){
        _booleanProvider = booleanProvider;
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

**not core solution**

Here is a guide if you do not use dotnetcore https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

`PerRequestLifetimeManager` is what you needed here

`Install-Package Unity.Mvc3`

At Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
 
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
 
    Bootstrapper.Initialise();
}
```

```
    public static class Bootstrapper
    {
        public static void Initialise()
        {
            var container = BuildUnityContainer();
 
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        }
 
        private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            
            Func<LifetimeManager> LM = () => { return new PerRequestLifetimeManager(); };

            container.RegisterType<IBooleanProvider, BooleanProvider>(LM());
            
            return container;
        }
    }
```

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBooleanProvider _booleanProvider;
    public HomeController (IBooleanProvider booleanProvider){
        _booleanProvider = booleanProvider;
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The project is currently in .net framework, but we want to move it to .net core soon, so thank you very much for providing both solutions! I'll test it on my solution and I'll mark as answer after!